# how to calculate how old someone will turn this year (in years) with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to find out how many children **turn a certain age this year**, but I think I need help from a mysql boffin on this one. This is what I have at the moment.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT count(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(dob) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(dob, 5))) FROM schs_students where (YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(dob) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(dob, 5)))=? and gender=1 and house=2");
```

but it gives me the wrong answers. I get the correct age on each child using

```
SELECT NOW()-schs_students.dob as age`
```

but using the following gives the count as zero

```
SELECT count(NOW()-schs_students.dob) FROM schs_students where (NOW()-schs_students.dob)=? and gender=1 and house=2`
```

The `dob` is stored as a `DATE` in the database. The basic equation is this year (2015) - birthyear( eg 2009 to give 6).

**So why is the second count failing? Or why is the first one giving false figures** (It LOOKS like the first one gives a year short)?

The full code loop I am using is as follows

```
for ($i=6;$i<14;$i++)
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT count(NOW()-schs_students.dob) FROM schs_students where (NOW()-schs_students.dob)=? and gender=1 and house=2");
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$i);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    if ($row)
    {
        $total=$row[0];
        echo "<td>{$total}</td>";
        //echo $total." of them are {$i} this year.<br/>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this with SQL.  Let SQL bring back the birthdates; write a JavaScript function that takes in the birthdate and date for which you want to calculate the age.  It'll be easier to write and test in JavaScript.  It'll be reusable in other contexts as well.  I'd write two methods: one that takes two arguments (birthdate and date on which to calculate age) and another that takes only one (birthdate) that calls the other with current date as the default.  Think curry.

Comment: Yup, there are other ways, but I am only looking for a mysqli solution here with prepared statements, or reasons why it will not work.

Comment: Of course it can work.  I gave some reasons why you wouldn't want to do the complete job in MySQL.  It's your choice.

Comment: Sorry @duffymo, didn't mean to offend, so I guess I should have elaborated. I am very familiar with php, but less so with MySql primarily as I  usually do it in php, so when doing this function I just decided to expand my knowledge on MySql. I couldn't find anything with google or SO search that helped, so asked the question. Hence my short comment above. I really do appreciated your help, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need one function in MySQL, namely `TIMESTAMPDIFF`:

```
 SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '1970-06-01 05:45:33', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Now for number of students turning a certain age *today*:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM schs_students where 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, schs_students.dob, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=? and gender=1 and house=2
```

Obviously, `schs_students.dob` needs to be `DATETIME` not just `char`.

Number of students turning a certain age this *year* will be a little more difficult...actually for year, I guess the cutt-off would be December 31st, so use that date:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM schs_students where 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, schs_students.dob, concat(Year(NOW()),'-12-31'))=? and gender=1 and house=2
```

Comment: You are leaving out the count, and the dob.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, developerwjk isn't writing your code for you, just illustrating the function to use.

Comment: true @Marcus, but I could not get that one to work for me (It's an answer to another question on SO somewhere).

Comment: @developerwjk .Hmm, I think that helps... let me look and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thank you that worked. The key to my problem methinks was count(*). Your last line did the job 100%. As what I am looking for involves age groups for sport I think changing the date to March will probably be the final solution, but I am awaiting confirmation from competing schools. Thanks again.